# php (empty($_GET)) transient errors

Tags: php

I am getting an *transient* error which I think is linked to this statement

```
$rs = (empty($_GET["rs"])?0:$_GET["rs"]);
```

1. Could someone explain this notation please
2. Is there a better way of writing this statement to include the trim function (as is suspect this may be an issue)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [ternary expression](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) that does exactly this:

```
if (empty($_GET["rs"]))
{
    $rs = 0;
}
else
{
    $rs = $_GET["rs"];
}
```

To trim the results, you can do

```
$rs = (empty($_GET["rs"])?0:trim($_GET["rs"]));
```

Or if you wish to use the expanded expression,

```
if (empty($_GET["rs"]))
{
    $rs = 0;
}
else
{
    $rs = trim($_GET["rs"] );
}
```